# Xen Server 6.2 Upgrade to SP1

Tags: xen, xenserver

I installed Xen server 6.2 and I am currently playing around with it. I managed to install 1 vm, and I have applied all hotfixes available up to the Service Pack 1. That specific patch gives me an error.
The command `xe patch-list` shows the following:

```
uuid ( RO)                    : 59128f15-92cd-4dd9-8fbe-a0115d1b07a2
              name-label ( RO): XS62E002
        name-description ( RO): Public Availability: security fixes to Xen
                    size ( RO): 1743501
                   hosts (SRO): e83b908b-aed4-4570-a32e-d2ce9fb7db04
    after-apply-guidance (SRO): restartHost


uuid ( RO)                    : dedcc0dd-d8f3-4f76-90ca-92697c7a44f0
              name-label ( RO): XS62E001
        name-description ( RO): Public Availability: Xapi fixes
                    size ( RO): 6625641
                   hosts (SRO): e83b908b-aed4-4570-a32e-d2ce9fb7db04
    after-apply-guidance (SRO): restartXAPI


uuid ( RO)                    : d9c753b9-a15b-4a31-897b-97fdae609031
              name-label ( RO): XS62E009
        name-description ( RO): Public Availability: security fixes to Xen
                    size ( RO): 1744205
                   hosts (SRO): e83b908b-aed4-4570-a32e-d2ce9fb7db04
    after-apply-guidance (SRO): restartHost


uuid ( RO)                    : 0850b186-4d47-11e3-a720-001b2151a503
              name-label ( RO): XS62ESP1
        name-description ( RO): Public Availability: XenServer 6.2 Service Pack 1 (SP1)
                    size ( RO): 218600009
                   hosts (SRO): 
    after-apply-guidance (SRO): restartHost


uuid ( RO)                    : ff202d2d-2812-4c6b-b500-2f4701de7bc4
              name-label ( RO): XS62E011
        name-description ( RO): Public Availability: Storage and ISCSI fixes
                    size ( RO): 845698
                   hosts (SRO): e83b908b-aed4-4570-a32e-d2ce9fb7db04
    after-apply-guidance (SRO): restartHost


uuid ( RO)                    : a4251789-ce6c-4726-942c-3cddbadcaca6
              name-label ( RO): XS62E012
        name-description ( RO): Public Availability: Fixes for Dom0 kernel issues
                    size ( RO): 35767767
                   hosts (SRO): e83b908b-aed4-4570-a32e-d2ce9fb7db04
    after-apply-guidance (SRO): restartHost


uuid ( RO)                    : 83bca9f6-4ae5-45f9-9426-440216f73797
              name-label ( RO): XS62E010
        name-description ( RO): Public Availability: Fix for GPU pass through
                    size ( RO): 252927
                   hosts (SRO): e83b908b-aed4-4570-a32e-d2ce9fb7db04
    after-apply-guidance (SRO): 


uuid ( RO)                    : aeff92a9-2c60-43eb-b34e-14e4132b411c
              name-label ( RO): XS62E005
        name-description ( RO): Public Availability: Toolstack fixes
                    size ( RO): 9315631
                   hosts (SRO): e83b908b-aed4-4570-a32e-d2ce9fb7db04
    after-apply-guidance (SRO): restartXAPI


uuid ( RO)                    : 5579f1f0-ff83-11e2-b778-0800200c9a66
              name-label ( RO): XS62E004
        name-description ( RO): Public Availability: Fixes for Dom0 kernel issues
                    size ( RO): 35766769
                   hosts (SRO): e83b908b-aed4-4570-a32e-d2ce9fb7db04
    after-apply-guidance (SRO): restartHost
```

This is the version of the installation:

```
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: XenServer
Description:    XenServer release 6.2.0-70446c (xenenterprise)
Release:    6.2.0-70446c
Codename:   xenenterprise
```

When I run `xe patch-upload file-name=XS62ESP1.xsupdate`, I get the expected `UUID`. Then when I run `xe patch-pool-apply uuid=xxxxx` I receive the following error:

> The patch precheck stage failed with an unknown error.  See attached
>   info for more details. patch: 0850b186-4d47-11e3-a720-001b2151a503
>   (XS62ESP1) info: XenServer Tools ISO must be ejected from all running
>   VMs.

After a lot of searching I run the command `xe vm-cd-eject --multiple` but I receive another error:

> Operation could not be performed because the drive is empty vbd:
>   6028ca4a-ece6-dcea-0688-0e81594738e4

There are no vms running. I have restarted the host many times.

As always any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, I deleted the one VM I had running and tried the update again to no avail.
I asked for help on the Citrix forums but the solutions they gave me did not help so I performed a clean install of Xen Server 6.2 and applied the SP1 hotfix right away. That worked. From there on I could install the rest of the fixes that pertain to SP1 only.